# alsamixer can see microphone, but pulseaudio doesn't

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, microphone

I've installed Ubuntu 15.04 on my Pixel LS laptop with a patched kernel (https://github.com/tsowell/linux-samus). Problem is - pulseaudio (`pavucontrol`) doesn't recognize the microphone. If I run `alsamixer`, mute speakers enable headphones and unmute stereo microphones - I can hear microphone input in my headphones (more details: https://github.com/tsowell/linux-samus/issues/4).

How can I make pulse recognize my microphone? Can someone at least nudge me in the right direction? Thanks.

**UPDATE:** `alsa-info` dump: http://pastebin.ca/3004491